# Is there a way to remove rows of a dataframe that follow a pattern in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the following format:

```
6/6/2019            
No. sex ID      weight(g)
1   f   0.001%Q 207
2   f   0.001%Q 198
3   f   0.001%Q 209
4   f   0.01%S  215
5   f   0.01%S  228
6   f   0.01%S  219
7   m   0.001%Q 303
8   m   0.001%Q 301
9   m   0.001%Q 319
10  m   0.01%S  303
11  m   0.01%S  305
12  m   0.01%S  295

6/7/2019            
No. sex ID       weight(g)
1   f   0.0025%Q 212
2   f   0.0025%Q 204
3   f   0.0025%Q 218
4   f   0.04%S   219
5   f   0.04%S   232
6   f   0.04%S   227
7   m   0.0025%Q 316
8   m   0.0025%Q 307
9   m   0.0025%Q 322
10  m   0.04%S   311
11  m   0.04%S   316
12  m   0.04%S   301
```

I would like to combine the two datasets, but make an additional column for the date of the dataset (to differentiate the two). Is there a way to remove the row containing the date and add it as a repeated value for an additional column the length of the dataset?

Comment: Can you share data as `dput` to understand how it is stored? `dput(dataframe_name)` .

Comment: I am not able to share the actual dataset for security reasons unfortunately, although I am trying to adapt it in R to share the ```dput```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two dataframes look like these:

```
df1 <- data.frame(No. = 1:12, 
                  sex = c(rep("f", 6), rep("m", 6)),
                  ID = c("0.0025%Q", "0.0025%Q", "0.0025%Q", "0.04%S", 
                         "0.04%S", "0.04%S", "0.0025%Q", "0.0025%Q", 
                         "0.0025%Q", "0.04%S", "0.04%S", "0.04%S"),
                  weight = c("207", "198", "209", "215", "228", "219", 
                             "303", "301", "319", "303", "305", "295"))

df2 <- data.frame(No. = 1:12, 
                 sex = c(rep("f", 6), rep("m", 6)),
                 ID = c("0.001%Q", "0.001%Q", "0.001%Q", "0.01%S", 
                        "0.01%S", "0.01%S", "0.001%Q", "0.001%Q", "0.001%Q", "0.01%S", 
                        "0.01%S", "0.01%S"),
                 weight = c("212", "204", "218", "219", "232", "227", 
                            "316", "307", "322", "311", "316", "301"))
```

then the solution is straightforward: you take the date for each and replicate it the number of rows in each dataframe:

```
df1$date <- rep("6/6/2019", nrow(df1))
df2$date <- rep("6/7/2019", nrow(df2))
```

and row-bind the two data frames using `rbind`:

```
df_combined <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

to obtain the combined dataframe:

```
df_combined
   No. sex       ID weight     date
1    1   f 0.0025%Q    207 6/6/2019
2    2   f 0.0025%Q    198 6/6/2019
3    3   f 0.0025%Q    209 6/6/2019
4    4   f   0.04%S    215 6/6/2019
5    5   f   0.04%S    228 6/6/2019
6    6   f   0.04%S    219 6/6/2019
7    7   m 0.0025%Q    303 6/6/2019
8    8   m 0.0025%Q    301 6/6/2019
9    9   m 0.0025%Q    319 6/6/2019
10  10   m   0.04%S    303 6/6/2019
11  11   m   0.04%S    305 6/6/2019
12  12   m   0.04%S    295 6/6/2019
13   1   f  0.001%Q    212 6/7/2019
14   2   f  0.001%Q    204 6/7/2019
15   3   f  0.001%Q    218 6/7/2019
16   4   f   0.01%S    219 6/7/2019
17   5   f   0.01%S    232 6/7/2019
18   6   f   0.01%S    227 6/7/2019
19   7   m  0.001%Q    316 6/7/2019
20   8   m  0.001%Q    307 6/7/2019
21   9   m  0.001%Q    322 6/7/2019
22  10   m   0.01%S    311 6/7/2019
23  11   m   0.01%S    316 6/7/2019
24  12   m   0.01%S    301 6/7/2019
```

**EDIT**:

Since you do not have several but only a single dataframe, here's another solution. The first critical step is to read-in the file properly, meaning, in your case, to strip the white space behind the variable names; this is achieved by the argument `strip.white = T`:

```
df <- read.table("Your path/Your dataframe.txt", header=F, strip.white = T, sep="\t", quote="", comment.char="")
```

The next step, equally critical, is to convert all the data to character:

```
df[,1:4] <- lapply(df[1:4], as.character)
```

Set all empty fields to "NA":

```
df[df==""] <- "NA"
```

Re-name the column names with the right values:

```
colnames(df) <- df[2,]
```

Grab the dates that you want to insert into a new column:

```
dates <- df[c(1,16),1]
```

Delete rows that have now become unnecessary:

```
df <- df[-c(1:2,15:17),]
```

And, finally, create the desired new column with the repeated dates:

```
df$date <- c(rep(dates[1], 12), rep(dates[2], 12))
```

The final result is this:

```
df
   No. sex       ID weight(g)   date
3    1   f  0.001%Q       207 6/6/19
4    2   f  0.001%Q       198 6/6/19
5    3   f  0.001%Q       209 6/6/19
6    4   f   0.01%S       215 6/6/19
7    5   f   0.01%S       228 6/6/19
8    6   f   0.01%S       219 6/6/19
9    7   m  0.001%Q       303 6/6/19
10   8   m  0.001%Q       301 6/6/19
11   9   m  0.001%Q       319 6/6/19
12  10   m   0.01%S       303 6/6/19
13  11   m   0.01%S       305 6/6/19
14  12   m   0.01%S       295 6/6/19
18   1   f 0.0025%Q       212 6/7/19
19   2   f 0.0025%Q       204 6/7/19
20   3   f 0.0025%Q       218 6/7/19
21   4   f   0.04%S       219 6/7/19
22   5   f   0.04%S       232 6/7/19
23   6   f   0.04%S       227 6/7/19
24   7   m 0.0025%Q       316 6/7/19
25   8   m 0.0025%Q       307 6/7/19
26   9   m 0.0025%Q       322 6/7/19
27  10   m   0.04%S       311 6/7/19
28  11   m   0.04%S       316 6/7/19
29  12   m   0.04%S       301 6/7/19
```

Depending on how many internal divisions you have in your real dataframe, some of these steps might need some further refinement and automation.

Comment: I actually have one dataframe with a row of spaces in between the two datasets that begin with the dates. I am not sure how to separate them to then further manipulate the data

Comment: 5, I typed only a sample of my data

Comment: Yes! Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the data as shown in the `dput` below we can get the data in a list and for each dataframe do :

1) Give new names to the dataframe from the 2nd row

2) Add new column using the information from the 1st row

3) Remove first 2 rows

We then bind these datasets together.

```
list_df <- list(df1, df2)

do.call(rbind, c(lapply(list_df, function(df) {
                 names(df) <- df[2, ]
                 df$new_col <- na.omit(unlist(df[1, ]))
                 df <- df[-c(1, 2), ]
                 df
}), make.row.names = FALSE))

#   No. sex       ID weight(g)  new_col
#1    1   f  0.001%Q       207 6/6/2019
#2    2   f  0.001%Q       198 6/6/2019
#3    3   f  0.001%Q       209 6/6/2019
#4    4   f   0.01%S       215 6/6/2019
#5    5   f   0.01%S       228 6/6/2019
#6    6   f   0.01%S       219 6/6/2019
#7    7   m  0.001%Q       303 6/6/2019
#8    8   m  0.001%Q       301 6/6/2019
#9    9   m  0.001%Q       319 6/6/2019
#10  10   m   0.01%S       303 6/6/2019
#11  11   m   0.01%S       305 6/6/2019
#12  12   m   0.01%S       295 6/6/2019
#13   1   f 0.0025%Q       212 6/7/2019
#14   2   f 0.0025%Q       204 6/7/2019
#15   3   f 0.0025%Q       218 6/7/2019
#16   4   f   0.04%S       219 6/7/2019
#17   5   f   0.04%S       232 6/7/2019
#18   6   f   0.04%S       227 6/7/2019
#19   7   m 0.0025%Q       316 6/7/2019
#20   8   m 0.0025%Q       307 6/7/2019
#21   9   m 0.0025%Q       322 6/7/2019
#22  10   m   0.04%S       311 6/7/2019
#23  11   m   0.04%S       316 6/7/2019
#24  12   m   0.04%S       301 6/7/2019
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("6/6/2019", "No.", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), V2 = c(NA, "sex", 
"f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m"), 
V3 = c(NA, "ID", "0.001%Q", "0.001%Q", "0.001%Q", "0.01%S", 
"0.01%S", "0.01%S", "0.001%Q", "0.001%Q", "0.001%Q", "0.01%S", 
"0.01%S", "0.01%S"), V4 = c(NA, "weight(g)", "207", "198", 
"209", "215", "228", "219", "303", "301", "319", "303", "305", 
"295")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("6/7/2019", "No.", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), V2 = c(NA, "sex", 
"f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m"), 
V3 = c(NA, "ID", "0.0025%Q", "0.0025%Q", "0.0025%Q", "0.04%S", 
"0.04%S", "0.04%S", "0.0025%Q", "0.0025%Q", "0.0025%Q", "0.04%S", 
"0.04%S", "0.04%S"), V4 = c(NA, "weight(g)", "212", "204", 
"218", "219", "232", "227", "316", "307", "322", "311", "316", 
"301")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```